# Disallow nfc app to take higher priority in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc

I am working on an application which is nfc specific. 
The problem is, when there is an ongoing call and I touch the tag, my application launches.

Here, the priority of my application should be low. it should not launch the app, unless the call is finished.

I tried android:priority=-1000. But it simply does not work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not quite clear under what circumstances a user would be tapping an NFC tag while on a call. That being said, there are broadcasts for finding out call status, IIRC. Listen to those, and enable/disable your NFC activity via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. I am not sure whether you can get this to be 100% reliable, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I will surely try out.

Comment: I wanted to know as to why does this happen. Is it because NFC has the highest priority above all?